# Regex match parenthesis

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following string:

```
The service(s), foo bar
```

I have a regex that checks if the words 'The' and 'service(s)' are contained within the string. I'm supposed to escape the brackets with backslash, but it does not seem to work. I must use the logical structure of this Regex. Can you help me fix the escaping?

Not working:

```
(^(?=.*\b(?i)The(?-i)\b)(?=.*\b(?i)service\(s\)(?-i)\b).*$)
```

Target language is C#.

Comment: put your regex within @""

Comment: Remove last `\b` token

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closing parenthesis in `service(s)` asserts that next immediate position is a non-word boundary. So you don't need last `\b` token since you possibly meant a non-word boundary `\B`. I don't think you need to set and unset case-insensitive modifier either:

```
(?i)(?=.*\bThe\b)(?=.*\bservice\(s\)\B).*$
```

Comment: Very interesting thanks. I understand the difference now.

Comment: Is there a boundary marker that ignores whether the boundary is word or non-word?

Comment: Maybe when you remove boundary token? @Ashton

Comment: Yes. Ok. Need to get used to think like regex. Appreciate the help!